# How to do apache htaccess ban by ip with the some exception?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ip-blocking

P.S.: Sorry me and please be lenient with my English.

I have the situation when some IP must blocked and better way for this on my mind - htaccess. It cause I have many entry points. It easy and works fine...

I do:

```
<Files *>
    Order allow,deny
    deny from aaa.aaa.aaa.aaa/aa
    deny from bbb.bbb.bbb.bbb/bb
    Allow from all
</Files>
```

BUT! There one more things. I have a few devices which should be allowed access even if they go through the denied IP.

I can't install some module for Apache. So I need some simply way for decide it.

Can someone give me some ways or some tricks for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some way of identifying those devices, then you can add an environment variable to set up an exception and use [access control by environment variable](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html#env). For example, if you can do it by user-agent:

```
SetEnvIf User-Agent SpecialUA UAException=1
<Files *>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from UAException=1
    Deny from aaa.aaa.aaa.aaa/aa
    Deny from bbb.bbb.bbb.bbb/bb
    Allow from all
</Files>
```

See also [SetEnvIf](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/de/mod/mod_setenvif.html#setenvif). I am linking to Apache 2.2 docs since you are using the old syntax which has been updated in 2.4.